# Syntax error setOnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

ok if you didnt see my previous question I asked how 2 Command button to import text to textview from edittext using Scanner? Here is what I have done:

I keep geting this error

> "Syntax error on token
>   "setOnClickListener",
>   VariableDeclaratorId expected after
>   this token"

what am I missing or doing wrong?

```
package test.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import java.util.Scanner;
import android.R.layout;
public class test extends Activity {

    Scanner what = (new Scanner(System.in));
    private int addbtn;
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(addbtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener = (new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int txtbox;
            EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(txtbox);
            int tv1;
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(tv1);  
            txt.setText( txt.getText().toString() );}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing brace `}` on the `new OnClickListener` block.

Also you shouldn't be attempting `Button btn = (Button) findViewById(addbtn);` before the `onCreate(...)` method has called `setContentView(...)`.

On top of that, `addbtn` isn't a valid resource id.

Use findViewById() method before `setContentView(...)`.

Comment: thank you very much what would u suggest as a valid resource?

Comment: @ricardo123: Instead of using `addbtn` you need to use a resource id in the form `R.id.myButton`. Use the id you have given your `Button` in your `main.xml` layout file. Also, move the button code into `onCreate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

On top of which your closing brackets look messed up.  What's matching the ( before the new onClickListener?